# How do the cuSPARSE and cuBLAS libraries deal with memory allocated using cudaMallocPitch?

Tags: memory, cuda, sparse-matrix

I am implementing a simple routine that performs sparse matrix - dense matrix multiplication using cusparseScsrmm from cuSPARSE. This is part of a bigger application that could allocate memory on GPU using cudaMalloc (more than 99% of the time) or cudaMallocPitch (very rarely used). I have a couple of questions regarding how cuSPARSE deals with pitched memory:

1) I passed in pitched memory into the cuSPARSE routine but the results were incorrect (as expected, since there is no way to pass in the pitch as an argument). Is there a way to get these libraries working with memory allocated using cudaMallocPitch?

2) What is the best way to deal with this? Should I just add a check in the calling function, to enforce that the memory **not** be allocated using pitched mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sparse matrix operations, the concept of pitched data has no relevance anyway.

For dense matrix operations  most operations don't directly support a "pitch" to the data per se, however various operations can operate on a sub-matrix.  With a particular caveat, it should be possible for such operations to handle pitched or unpitched data.  Any time you see a CUBLAS (or CUSPARSE) operation that accepts "leading dimension" arguments, those arguments could be used to encompass a pitch in the data.

Since the "leading dimension" parameter is specified in *matrix elements*, and the pitch is (usually) specified in bytes, the caveat here is that the pitch is evenly divisible by the size of the matrix element in question, so that the pitch (in bytes) can be converted to a "leading dimension" parameter specified in matrix elements.  I would expect that this would be typically possible for `char`, `int`, `float`, `double` and similar types, as I believe the pitch quantity returned by `cudaMallocPitch` will usually be evenly divisible by 16.  But there is no stated guarantee of this, so proper run-time checking is advised, if you intend to use this approach.

For example, it should be possible to perform a CUBLAS matrix-matrix multiply ([gemm](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm)) on pitched data, with appropriate specification of the `lda`, `ldb` and `ldc` parameters.

The [operation you indicate](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-csrmm) does offer such leading dimension parameters for the dense matrices involved.

If 99% of your use-cases don't use pitched data, I would either not support pitched data at all, or else, for operations where no leading dimension parameters are available, copy the pitched data to an unpitched buffer for use in the desired operation.  A device-to-device pitched to unpitched copy can run at approximately the rate of memory bandwidth, so it might be fast enough to not be a serious issue for 1% of the use cases.